# what is a user coordinate system when talking about graphics or svg

Tags: svg, autocad

I am reading up on panning and zooming svg images and I keep coming across the expression

> new user coordinate system

For example in [this post](https://www.sarasoueidan.com/blog/svg-coordinate-systems/)

It states

> A new user space (i.e., a new current coordinate system) can also be established by specifying transformations

I generally get what it means, it is creating a new user coordinate system at a new origin but I'd really like a good definition.

Can anyone supply one

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds like you basically have the gist of it.

An SVG starts out with an initial **user coordinate system** which matches 1:1 with the **viewport coordinate system**.*  It's origin (0,0) is at the top left of the viewport.

If a container element (such as a `<g>`) has a `transform` applied to it, then we consider that it establishes a **new user coordinate system**.  All the child elements inside that container element have no idea that they have a location somewhere else on the page.  It's (0,0) may not be at the top left of the viewport at all.  It may be on a different angle. And it may be scaled or skewed relative to the user coordinate system of its parent.  1 unit in the parent's coordinate system, may be 5 in this one.

So why is this useful?  Well, at it's simplest level, it's an easy way to move a group of shapes to a different position on the page.  Some designs, you may wish to construct, may be easier to wrap your head around if you design them with its centre at (0,0) and then move them to their final place later.  Think of a star shape, or a shape with symmetry.

But you can also have a whole stack of nested user coordinate systems.  Picture an SVG representing a person's arm, with joints at the shoulder, elbow and wrist.

```
<g id="shoulder" transform="...">
  <path .../><!-- upper arm -->

  <g id="elbow" transform="...">
    <path .../><!-- lower arm -->

    <g id="wrist" transform="...">
      <path .../><!-- hand -->
    </g>
  </g>
</g>
```

An arrangement like this is very useful for animation purposes.  You can position the elbow at any angle you choose.  Then if you rotate the shoulder, the whole arm stays together in its existing pose.  The lower parts of the arm don't care what position or angle the upper parts might have.

If they weren't nested like this, you'd have to explicitly update the position of the lower arm and hand every time the shoulder moved.  And reposition the hand every time you moved the lower arm.

So a tree of nested transforms like this is the norm in most graphical scene desciption files.  Both in 2D and 3D.

I hope this explanation helped.

** Unless of course, the SVG has a viewBox. That will result in the initial user coordinate system being transformed so that the viewBox fits into the viewport.*

Comment: brilliant, I could not find anything online like this